# need to change the umask value dynamically

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Whatever the umask value I want to change it into `umask 077` dynamically.

```
sed -d 's/umask [0-999]/umask 077/g' /etc/bashrc,
```

I have tried the above one but it's not working.

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/\(umask \)[0-9]\{1,\}/\1 077/g' /etc/bashrc`

Comment: `[0-999]` doesn’t do what you think it does; it’s the same as `[0-9]` and only matches a *single* digit.

Comment: Great Biffen, it's working but plese let me know what is the use of  {1,\}/\1

Comment: It looks like  it was @WiktorStribiżew's solution that worked for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed -i 's/\(umask \)[0-9]\{1,\}/\1 077/g' /etc/bashrc
```

It means

- `-i` - the `/etc/bashrc` will be changed inline
- `\(umask \)[0-9]\{1,\}` - the regex pattern that matches

  - `\(umask \)` - Group 1: `umask` + space
  - `[0-9]\{1,\}` - 1 or more occurrences of any ASCII digit
- `\1 077` - the contents of Group 1, space, `077`
- `g' -` global` modifier, match and replace all non-overlapping occurrences.